# Android - launch another PreferenceScreen relative to the package

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I am trying to launch another PreferenceScreen from within a SreferenceScreen

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Advanced" >
    <Preference
        android:key="mykey"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:title="Advanced settings">
        <intent  android:targetPackage="com.mypackage"  android:targetClass="com.mypackage.SettingsAdvancedActivity"/>
</Preference>
```

It works fine but I want to change it so that it would be relative to the package, something like

```
<<PreferenceCategory android:title="Advanced" >
    <Preference
        android:key="mykey"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:title="Advanced settings">
        <intent  android:targetPackage="."  android:targetClass=".SettingsAdvancedActivity"/>
</Preference>
```

is it possible? You might ask why? In case I have to change package name life would be easier

Comment: "In case I have to change package name life would be easier" if you are planning to deploy this on the market and you decide to change package names there is nothing that will make life easier =p. Seriously though if you change package names it will be considered a different application from the markets perspective. Doing so will disallow your users from updating the old version to the new version.

Comment: I was planing to a pro version of the app in the feature

Comment: Ahh, I have seen some apps that use different package for trial / PRO version. It should be decided on a case by case basis, however I tend to think that the users experience is better if you stick to 1 application that is able to "unlock" pro features rather than having them need to download an entirely separate one. Also if someone is going from free to paid, and they don't uninstall free before getting the paid one they will have 2 identical icon/labels for your app in the app drawer which can be frustrating to them to figure out which is which to install the free one.